# Heap exhaustion while compiling lapack system with SBCL

Tags: heap-memory, common-lisp, sbcl

While compiling the lapack system from the f2cl library, SBCL drops into the low-level debugger with this error message about heap exhaustion:

```
Heap exhausted during garbage collection: 0 bytes available, 64 requested.
Gen  Boxed Unboxed   LgBox LgUnbox  Pin       Alloc     Waste        Trig      WP GCs Mem-age
 0       0       0       0       0    0           0         0    26843545       0   0  0.0000
 1   26205   12796       0       0    9  1277771072    213696   767547401   39001   1  1.3696
 2   14599   27405     117      18   88  1114241264 266569488     2000000   42139   0  0.8257
 3       0       0       0       0    0           0         0     2000000       0   0  0.0000
 4       0       0       0       0    0           0         0     2000000       0   0  0.0000
 5       0       0       0       0    0           0         0     2000000       0   0  0.0000
 6     449     220      64      47    0    24788848    770192     2000000     780   0  0.0000
 7       0       0       0       0    0           0         0     2000000       0   0  0.0000
           Total bytes allocated    =    2416801184
           Dynamic-space-size bytes =    2684354560
GC control variables:
   *GC-INHIBIT* = true
   *GC-PENDING* = true
   *STOP-FOR-GC-PENDING* = false
fatal error encountered in SBCL pid 31717(tid 0x7fbb53033280):
Heap exhausted, game over.
```

I found postings on the maxima mailing list that recommend increasing the heap size with the `--dyanamic-space-size` option for sbcl, so I tried that. Even when I gave it as much memory as my RAM  (~7.44 GB) it still exhausted the heap, albeit after a much longer time. I'm not quite sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

System Specs: Arch Linux and SBCL 1.4.16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

High memory consumption during compilation may happen because you are asking a high amount of debugging information. I tried compiling `lapack`, which failed too.  It happens that in my `~/.sbclrc`, I have:

```
(sb-ext:restrict-compiler-policy 'debug 3)
(sb-ext:restrict-compiler-policy 'safety 3)
```

In a fresh SBCL, the compiler policy is as follows:

```
* (describe-compiler-policy)

  Basic qualities:
COMPILATION-SPEED = 1
DEBUG = 3
SAFETY = 3
SPACE = 1
SPEED = 1
INHIBIT-WARNINGS = 1
  Dependent qualities:
SB-C::CHECK-CONSTANT-MODIFICATION = 1 -> 3 (yes)
SB-C::TYPE-CHECK = 1 -> 3 (full)
SB-C::CHECK-TAG-EXISTENCE = 1 -> 3 (yes)
SB-C::LET-CONVERSION = 1 -> 0 (off)
SB-C:ALIEN-FUNCALL-SAVES-FP-AND-PC = 1 -> 3 (yes)
SB-C:VERIFY-ARG-COUNT = 1 -> 3 (yes)
SB-C::INSERT-DEBUG-CATCH = 1 -> 3 (yes)
SB-C::RECOGNIZE-SELF-CALLS = 1 -> 0 (no)
SB-C::FLOAT-ACCURACY = 1 -> 3 (full)
SB-C:INSERT-STEP-CONDITIONS = 1 -> 3 (full)
SB-C::COMPUTE-DEBUG-FUN = 1 -> 3 (yes)
SB-C::EVAL-STORE-SOURCE-FORM = 1 -> 3 (yes)
SB-C::PRESERVE-SINGLE-USE-DEBUG-VARIABLES = 1 -> 3 (yes)
SB-C::INSERT-ARRAY-BOUNDS-CHECKS = 1 -> 3 (yes)
SB-C::STORE-XREF-DATA = 1 -> 3 (yes)
SB-C:STORE-COVERAGE-DATA = 1 -> 0 (no)
SB-C::INSTRUMENT-CONSING = 1 -> 1 (no)
SB-C::STORE-CLOSURE-DEBUG-POINTER = 1 -> 0 (no)
SB-KERNEL:ALLOW-NON-RETURNING-TAIL-CALL = 1 -> 0 (no)
```

In particular, the policy is restricted as follows:

```
* (restrict-compiler-policy)

((SAFETY . 3) (DEBUG . 3))
```

Those are the minimal amount of debugging and safety required, which is thus at least 3 for both.
When I remove the debug restriction, with the following line:

```
* (restrict-compiler-policy 'debug)
((SAFETY . 3))
```

... then compiling the `lapack` system works, without changing the dynamic space size. Adding debugging information is fine when developing, and I'd encourage anyone to keep them at all time because you never know when you'll need to debug something, but in that case it is simply better to turn them off.

Comment: Requesting `debug` to be anything below `3` fixed the issue. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @ramenbytes Great!

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note to add: that's a very old version of SBCL. If you can, you may want to consider upgrading to the latest.